# How to register a customized http status code for flask?

Tags: python, flask

I want to add my own http status code to my Flask application. Here is my code:

```py
from werkzeug import exceptions

class UnrecognizedParametersOrCombination(exceptions.HTTPException):
    code = 460
    description = 'The query parameters or their combination are not recognized!'


exceptions.default_exceptions[460] = UnrecognizedParametersOrCombination
```

But when I call `abort(460)`, I got error:
`LookupError: no exception for 460`

It seems I didn't correctly register the new exception to werkzeug default exceptions. The official document is quite blur on this part. How should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I figured it out. According to the document:
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/errorhandling/
This is not doable. What we can do is to define an exception, and `raise()` it instead of `abort()` it. It seems now werkzeug doesn't support registering a customized http status code in its default exceptions any longer...

So now my working code is:

```py
from werkzeug import exceptions

class UnrecognizedParametersOrCombination(exceptions.HTTPException):
    code = 460
    description = 'The query parameters or their combination are not recognized!'


def handle_460(e):
    return render_template('460.html')


app.register_error_handler(UnrecognizedParametersOrCombination, handle_460)
```

And now I need to use `raise UnrecognizedParametersOrCombination()` instead of `abort(460)` for responding. And so, the response is a 200 instead of a non-officially-supported 460.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be doing this, as you would break the RFCs associated with the HTTP status codes. HTTP status codes are supposed to be universal and not misused. I'd recommend responding some JSON, like "status": "460", if you want to use your own debugging codes, just don't use them as HTTP responses.

Comment: Why can't you have different RFC error codes? Not all of them are used. (I.e. 460 has no meaning that is still relevant: https://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc460)

Answer (score 0):

Tried abort mapping?

`abort.mappings[460] = UnrecognizedParametersOrCombination`

Comment: Seems this api is not available any longer since 0.11